# HP Z200 DisplayPort is not working with DVI LCD screen

Tags: windows-7, dvi, displayport, nvidia-graphics-card

I finalized the process of imaging a bunch of Z200. Right now, I need to setup a computer running Windows 7 with a DVI screen and the other one, connected with the DisplayPort/DVI adapter. This one is not working...

I have a auto-input scan screen but it doesn't recognize it. In the nVidia control panel, I'm not able to detect the DP screen.

Is there something I need to do with that?

> CARD: nVidia Quadro FX580
>
> HP Z200: QuadCore, 6go RAM, 500go HDD and of course an optical mouse!
>
> Screen: HP L1940T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tested the adapter?  If you are using an adapter in my experience it's the most common point of failure.

Comment: I have 6... hold on my friend!

Comment: We finaly tried some of the adapter. It's working with a newer model of HP screen but I then tried it with another workstation and al of them are working fine now. Kind'a frakkin' weird!!!

Comment: So does it work OK with the original WS?